# I'm getting error with morphological mask

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, bitmask

I wrote a program that find 2 ROIs, selects them in 2 separate frames and then counts number of green pixels of each frame.
It works fine, but when I apply morphology masks for camera it gives me error: /home/pi/opencv/opencv-3.4.0/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1769: error: (-209) The lower boundary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a scalar in function inRange
How can I fix this?

Problem occurs here

`maskClose=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose) 
 maskFinal=maskClose ... for i in range(len(conts)): 
 x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[i]) area=maskFinal[y:y+h, x:x+w] pixcount = 
 cv2.inRange(area,lowerBound,upperBound ) pixNum = cv2.countNonZero(pixcount)`

Full code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import sys
prevNrOfContours = 0
lowerBound=np.array([43,53,30])
upperBound=np.array([132,255,255])


camera = PiCamera()
camera.rotation = 180
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 30
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
GREEN_MIN = np.array([0, 0, 0])
GREEN_MAX = np.array([0, 0, 0])



# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)
kernelOpen=np.ones((5,5))
kernelClose=np.ones((20,20))
# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
        img = frame.array
        imgHSV= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask=cv2.inRange(imgHSV,lowerBound,upperBound)
#morphology
        maskOpen=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
        maskClose=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)
        maskFinal=maskClose
        _, conts, _=cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        nrOfContours = len(conts)
        for i in range(len(conts)):
            x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[i])
            area=maskFinal[y:y+h, x:x+w] ######## problem is here
            pixcount = cv2.inRange(area,lowerBound,upperBound )
            pixNum = cv2.countNonZero(pixcount)
            print("Area No."+str(i), "Green pixels = " + str(no_black))
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow("area" + str(i), area)
        # close unnecessary windows
        if prevNrOfContours > nrOfContours:
          for i in range(nrOfContours, prevNrOfContours):
            cv2.destroyWindow("area" + str(i))
        prevNrOfContours = nrOfContours
        cv2.imshow("cam",img)

        # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
        if key == ord("q"):
                break
```

Comment: It would be useful if you included where in the code the error occurs. Also, try to simplify the code, it's not very nice to just dump all of your code here and expect someone to do the work of debugging. You are expected to make a [mcve], which implies removing everything that is not relevant to the error, leaving only a short piece of code that can be run by copy-pasting (i.e. in includes all data etc.). For example, I can't replicate your error because I don't have a Pi camera.

Comment: Problem occurs here
` maskClose=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)
    maskFinal=maskClose
 ...
for i in range(len(conts)):
            x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[i])
            area=maskFinal[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
            pixcount = cv2.inRange(area,lowerBound,upperBound )
            pixNum = cv2.countNonZero(pixcount) `

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information. Comments are meant to be temporary, we want your question to be complete and self-contained even if the comments are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a subimage of maskFinal. maskFinal is a binary image, which is incompatible with the 3 channel `lowerBound`.

To solve it you can actually drop the line `pixcount = cv2.inRange(area,lowerBound,upperBound )` The masked image has white for the green area's, so counting the nonzeros is enough.

Note: the current subimage includes the morphological transformations. If you do not want to count the pixels caused by those, you'll have to create a subimage of `mask`

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I know that it works when I use "area" instead of "mask" but then it returns unaccurate amount of pixels because of some false ROIs.
I need to count pixels exactly from the mask image